Manipulating stock composition through buying different vestment funds
Can somebody indirectly control which companies they own stocks in through index funds?
I did a quick investigation into how index funds work, and these are the main points I gathered:

An index fund can contain shares from competing companies within the same sector.
Not all index funds are the same regarding stock composition and asset allocation. If I understand that correctly, one index fund can have 100 shares of Coke and 50 shares of Pepsi while another index may have 50 shares of Coke and 100 shares of Pepsi.
Individual assets cannot be traded within the same fund.
You can own different index funds.

So if I don’t want to invest in Pepsi, but I do want to invest in Coke, I could buy more of the first index fund and none of the second index fund. However, if I change my mind and want to invest in Pepsi instead of Coke, I could sell all of my Coke heavy index funds to buy the Pepsi heavy index fund.
While this won’t completely eliminate investment in the least preferred stock, it will still change the investment levels to be more in line with whom I wish to invest in.
Do I understand this correctly?

While you can do what you propose, the fact that index funds can own shares from dozens, hundreds, or even thousands of companies, switching index funds is an inefficient method of investing in a particular company vs. their competitor.
You may find that unless you change to a completely different index being used to guide their investment, this will be harder than what you describe. All funds that try and match the S&P 500 will end up with similar weighting of the companies.
You can't ignore the impact of taxes if you aren't doing this in a tax deferred or tax free account.  Switching funds will come at a cost.
While a constantly changing index defeats the one of the purposes of investing in an index fund, the truth is they do change. Companies are added or removed from the index, and then from the funds tracking the index.
I have heard of some proposals to allow people to invest in an index fund, but exclude a sector or a particular company, but I haven't researched how they work.

Re: your last paragraph, many index providers create offshoots of indexes that exclude certain segments. e.g. https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/equity/sp-500-ex-financials/#overview. An ETF would just invest it the constituents of the "ex" fund to track it.

This question was more from the perspective of a large corporation with the resources to track all the variables you mentioned rather than for an individual. Although, I don’t see why an individual couldn’t develop an algorithm that would track all these variables for analysis.

Yes, you understand this correctly... assuming that the mix of stocks in the index, or in the fund tracking an approximation of it, do not change. Which they can, so if this is what you are trying to do, you should review it on a regular basis to make sure you are still happy with your choices.
If this sort of thing really matters to you, you may want to investigate funds which explicitly avoid particular kinds of stocks, and see if one of them matches your preferences. Note that this has very little impact in terms of affecting the companies; it is mostly a matter of what you feel comfortable owning a share in.
